# jqGrid not appearing in IE7

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to get jqGrid appearing in IE7. It's fine in IE8, but in IE7, it doesn't appear at all. It's using local data, although I've also added a reference to JSON2.js in case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: you should add JavaScript code which you use. Do you use compatibility mode of IE7? Do you installed [Developer Tools for IE7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359)? What error you get in the console?

Comment: Oleg: The problem was that there was an extra comma at the end of my postData section with nothing following it. IE8 seems to ignore it where IE7 raises it as an error.

Comment: It's well known problem. So it's recommended to debug the code (in developer tools for example). I personally verify all productive code on [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). If you set some options like "messy white space" and some other you can very good use the tool to improve quality of the code and to find errors like your current.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the postData section included 2 items, and after the 2nd item there was a rogue comma, so looked like:-

```
postData: {
    var1: 1,
    var2: 2,
    }
```

This passed through IE9 but in IE7 compatibility mode, it threw an error.